# Can I interrupt a "Count Rows" operation in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When I execute a query and right click in the results area, I get a pop-up menu with the following options:

- Save Grid as Report ...
- Single Record View ...
- Count Rows ...
- Find/Highlight ...
- Export ...

If I select "Count Rows", is there a way to interrupt the operation if it starts taking too long?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you don't seem to be able to.

When you select `Count Rows` from the context menu, it runs the count on the main UI thread, hanging the whole UI, potentially for minutes or hours.

It's best not to use that feature - just put `select count (*) from ( < your query here>)` which it runs properly on separate thread which can be cancelled.

Answer (score 3):

You can open an new instance of **`sql developer`** and kill the session counting the rows.
I do suggest using the **`select count(*)`** query though as it is less painful in the long run.